# How to get value of fields from given dictionary in Django python

Tags: python, django

I have used below query to get result from particular table.

industries.py:

```
from demo.models import IndustryCat1
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

class Industries:

    @staticmethod
    def getIndustries(indId):
        """
            Get contacts from contact_list where invitor id is same as given owner_id.
            Args:
                 user_id
            Returns:
                 contact user object
        """
        try:

            return IndustryCat1.objects.filter()


        except IndustryCat1.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import IndustryCat1
from demo.core.persistence.Industries import *
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.core import serializers
import json

def index(request):


    industry = Industries()
    qs = serializers.serialize("json", industry.getIndustries(1))

    return HttpResponse(qs)


    #return render(request, 'demo/test/isndustries_catagories.html', context)
```

Where qs is returning:

```
[{
    "model": "demo.industrycat1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Division A: Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing"
    }
}, {
    "model": "demo.industrycat1",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Division B: Mining"
    }
}, {
    "model": "demo.industrycat1",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Division C: Construction"
    }
}, {
    "model": "demo.industrycat1",
    "pk": 4,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Division D: Manufacturing"
    }
}]
```

I want to fetch values of "fields" index.
If not possible then please suggest what else I can use instead of serialize to fetch values within object returned by query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What values are you looking to retrieve? All the names?

Comment: value inside fields.

Comment: Is this for a particular model or for all models?

Comment: I have fetched records from a model using Django query set: IndustryCat1.objects.filter() and then serialize the result: serializers.serialize("json", industry.getIndustries()) as otherwise I was getting classname object.

Answer (score 1):

Get all names with a list comprehension.

```
names = [record['fields']['name'] for record in qs]
```

Get all `fields` with a list comprehension.

```
fields = [record['fields'] for record in qs]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @oluwafemi but I am getting TypeError: string indices must be integers. Where I have put given json into qs.

Comment: Oops! That's because your data is a json string.

Comment: Can you update your question with context about what you're doing?

Comment: Seen. So you want to return a json of names in fields from `index` view function, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
data = [
    {
        "model": "demo.industrycat1", 
        "pk": 1, 
        "fields": {
            "name": "Division A: Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "model": "demo.industrycat1", 
        "pk": 2, 
        "fields": {
            "name": "Division B: Mining"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "model": "demo.industrycat1", 
        "pk": 3, 
        "fields": {
            "name": "Division C: Construction"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "model": "demo.industrycat1",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Division D: Manufacturing"
        }
    }
]



print ([each_field["fields"]["name"] for each_field in data])
```